# Is there an equivalent in Java for Ruby's Digest::MD5.base64digest?

Tags: java, ruby

I would like to convert a Ruby code into Java. All is well, except a line:

```
digest = Digest::MD5.base64digest("#{width} #{height} #{unescaped_path} #{salt}")
digest.tr!('+/', '-_')
digest.tr!('=', '')
```

How would this chunk of code look alike in Java? I think it would be something like

```
digest = Base64.getDecoder().decode(width + " " + height + unescaped_path + salt);
```

however, `tr!` is unclear for me. It looks to be something like `replace`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Here is tr docs https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr

Comment: @PavelOganesyan unfortunately I have written my question after reading that page and realizing that it's confusing for me. Based on this page it seems that we replace characters in positions. But what does digest.tr!('|/', '-_') do? Is it replacing all + characters into - and all slash into _? Is this the effect? Or is it replacing only '+/' with '-_'?

Comment: @PavelOganesyan also, tr+('=', '') is this removing all = from the String?

Comment: You are totally correct: it replacing all + characters into - and all slash into _
And tr+('=', '') will remove all =

Comment: @PavelOganesyan thanks, I have implemented this in Java, the code looks like String digest = Base64.getDecoder().decode(width + " " + height + " " + path + " " + salt).toString().replace("+/", "-_").replace("=", "");

Comment: I'm not a rubyist, but I'm guessing that code calculates an MD5 hash and then base64-ecncodes the resulting byte array. Here's an article about [MD5 hashing in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-md5)... And you'll want to use a base64 ENCODER, not a decoder.

Comment: @dnault that's a very good point. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tr` method has two modes. One is where it maps characters in set A to characters in set B:

```
"ABBA".tr('ABC', 'DEF')
# => "DEED"
```

This requires mapping strings of identical length. If the replacement side is empty then instances of the characters in the matching set are deleted:

```
"ABBA".tr('A', '')
# => "BB"
```

`tr!` is an in-place version of `tr` but works the same.